# VB.NET - How to make textbox input only numbers, space, backspace/delete, decimals, and shortcuts

Tags: vb.net

My biggest problem here is to get the CTRL-V (Paste) to work. I've tested many ctrl-v ascii code but I got none of them to work. CtrlX and CtrlC works perfetly so I don't know what the problem is.
This is my half working code:

```
Private Sub alltb_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtF.KeyPress, txtCLL.KeyPress, txtCLU.KeyPress
    e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = "." Or e.KeyChar = " " Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 235 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 1 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 3 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 26 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 22 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 24)
End Sub
```

If you could suggest new code that will only allow numbers, decimals, space, backspace/delete, and shortcuts Or help me be able to use ctrlV, that would be really amazing and a big help!

Answer (score 0):

When you press `Ctrl+V` keys in an edit-box like the `TextBox` control, you actually request a string containing the text data on the system [`Clipboard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) if any. So, the `TextBox.KeyPress` event is not the right place to validate the pastes. You need a way to trap the `WM_PASTE` messages and validate the string that returns from the `Clipboard.GetText()` method.

For that and the keyboard inputs, create a new class and inherit from the `TextBox` control, override the `OnKeyPress` and `WndProc` methods to apply your input condition(s).

```vb
Public Class TextBoxEx
    Inherits TextBox

    Const WM_PASTE As Integer = &H302

    Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyPress(e As KeyPressEventArgs)
        If Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar) Then
            Dim s = Text.Insert(SelectionStart, e.KeyChar)

            If Not Decimal.TryParse(s.Replace(" ", ""), Nothing) Then
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If

        MyBase.OnKeyPress(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_PASTE AndAlso Clipboard.ContainsText() Then
            Dim s = Text.Remove(SelectionStart, SelectionLength).
                Insert(SelectionStart, Clipboard.GetText().Replace(" ", ""))
            If Not Decimal.TryParse(s, Nothing) Then Return
        End If

        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It's more complex than that even, because the the fact that what the user is pasting is a valid number doesn't mean that the result of pasting into the control will be.

Comment: @user18387401 Good morning Mr. John. Decimal + White Space inputs as the OP requested. More requirements, more to do.

Comment: Your code doesn't quite meet those requirements though. Either you should allow an arbitrary number of decimal points or you should only allow one. You are validating the input to ensure that it is a valid number, indicating that you're only allowing one, but what if the control already contains one? Your code would not allow the user to paste "1.23.4" into the empty control but it would allow them you type "1.2" and then paste "3.4" after it. There's a lot of edge cases like this to consider, which I know because I spent a lot of time considering them myself some years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Things are actually a bit more complex even than the first answer suggests because the user might select paste a valid number within another valid number to create an invalid input, so you need to validate the result of the paste, not just the text being pasted.

You also need to consider that the user might enter one or more characters that are valid but then leave a result that is not. Here's a basic implementation I wrote some years ago:

```vb
Imports System.Globalization

Public Class SimpleNumberBox
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

    Private Const WM_PASTE As Integer = &H302

    Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyPress(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
        Dim keyChar = e.KeyChar
        Dim formatInfo = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo

        If Char.IsControl(keyChar) OrElse _
           Char.IsDigit(keyChar) OrElse _
           ((keyChar = formatInfo.NegativeSign OrElse _
             keyChar = formatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator) AndAlso _
            Me.ValidateText(keyChar)) Then
            MyBase.OnKeyPress(e)
        Else
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnValidated(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If Not Decimal.TryParse(Me.Text, New Decimal) Then
            Me.Clear()
        End If

        MyBase.OnValidated(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If m.Msg <> WM_PASTE OrElse _
           Not Clipboard.ContainsText() OrElse _
           Me.ValidateText(Clipboard.GetText()) Then
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function ValidateText(ByVal newText As String) As Boolean
        Dim isValid = True
        Dim currentText = Me.Text
        Dim selectionStart = Me.SelectionStart
        Dim proposedText = currentText.Substring(0, selectionStart) & _
                           newText & _
                           currentText.Substring(selectionStart + Me.SelectionLength)

        If Not Decimal.TryParse(proposedText, _
                                NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign Or NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, _
                                Nothing, _
                                New Decimal) Then
            Dim formatInfo = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo
            Dim negativeSign = formatInfo.NegativeSign
            Dim decimalSeparator = formatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator

            isValid = (proposedText = negativeSign) OrElse _
                      (proposedText = decimalSeparator) OrElse _
                      (proposedText = negativeSign & decimalSeparator)
        End If

        Return isValid
    End Function

End Class
```

In case you're interested, [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?618778-Numeric-Text-Box) is a more rigorous implementation, although I'm not 100% sure that there aren't still some bugs in this one as I haven't looked at it for a long time.